# AWS.translate is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am writing the following lambda function in the aws website, trying to get the basics of aws translate working but i get the error AWS.translate is not a constructor

I have looked it up and it means translate is not in the aws-sdk version I have imported, but how can i make it so that is is?

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var translate = new AWS.translate();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var params = {
          SourceLanguageCode: 'en', /* required */
          TargetLanguageCode: 'es', /* required */
          Text: 'Hello World', /* required */
    };
    translate.translateText(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [`AWS.Translate()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Translate.html) not `AWS.translate()`.

Also, if working with `async`, prefer the `try`/`catch` version using `.promise()`:

```js
console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const translate = new AWS.Translate({ apiVersion: '2017-07-01' }); // Fix API version (best practice)

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      SourceLanguageCode: 'en', /* required */
      TargetLanguageCode: 'es', /* required */
      Text: 'Hello World', /* required */
    };
    const data = await translate.translateText(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate should be a capital `T` like this:

`var translate = new AWS.Translate();`

As documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Translate.html).